# Добавить цифру 0 к каждой цифре

Tags: delphi

**В Edit1 есть цифры:**

```
12345
```

**Как добавить к каждой цифре число ноль. То есть результат на выходе должен быть:**

```
1020304050
```

Ну вот пример мой, но мне кажется что это не совсем правильно:

```
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'0','00',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'1','10',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'2','20',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'3','30',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'4','40',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'5','50',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'6','60',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'7','70',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'8','80',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.Text:=StringReplace(Edit1.Text,'9','90',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Татьяна, совсем никаких идей? *(Нет необходимости выделять текст вопроса жирным шрифтом.)*

Comment: Пробуй циклом, так проще будет

Comment: @Igor, Добавила свой вариант в вопрос, но думаю что он не совсем правильный. Как бы кода много, посторений StringReplace.

Comment: @Татьяна цикл,цикл и еще раз, цикл

Comment: можно посимвольно брать строку и в новую вписывать символ + 0. Можно преобразоывать в число каждй и умножать на 10. Можно разделить на символы и склеить обратно через 0,  можно регулярками заменить `(\d)` на условно `$10`. вариантов тьма.

Comment: Можно через copy вставку делать, в цикле, по чётным позициям слева-направо. Позиция 2 существует - добавить ноль. Позиция 4 существует - добавить ноль, и так далее. Добавить можно copy, ф-ция insert не помню есть в делфи аналог или нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте прочитаем заголовок и буквально запишем каждое действие из него с заимствованием из  Евангелия от Иоанна:

`Вначале было Слово:`

```
s := '';
```

`к каждой цифре (из Edit1)`:

```
for i := 1 to Length(Edit1.Text) do
```

`Добавить цифру 0`:

```
   s := s + Edit1.Text[i] + '0';
```

Наконец вернём это Слово первоисточнику

```
 Edit1.Text := s;
```

Comment: чет получается, что вначале было пусто :)

Comment: @teran Зато в конце "и увидел он, что это хорошо" ;)

Comment: @MBo, Все работает идеально. Сейчас добавлю полный код. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря пользователю [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo), на этом ресурсе, получился вот такой код. Вот полный код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
S:String;
i: Integer;
begin
 s := '';
 for i := 1 to Length(Edit1.Text) do
  s := s + Edit1.Text[i] + '0';
   Edit1.Text := s;
end;
end.
```